# customizing size of emacs windows in twm, depending on the vnc session

Tags: emacs, vnc, window, twm

I connect to the same Unix system (that runs tab windows manager, twm) via vnc. I connect from a laptop with a small screen and from a workstations with a large screen. I have started two different vnc sessions with two different `--geometry` setting because of the different screens (I like to use the full screen in both cases). The two sessions share the same emacs initialisation file. The size of emacs window I like on the workstation screen is too large for fitting the laptop screen. The part of the configuration file where I set the size is like the following:

```
;; set font
(cond
 ((string-equal system-type "windows-nt") ; Microsoft Windows
  (progn
    nil )
  )
 ((string-equal system-type "darwin")   ; Mac OS X
  (progn
    (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "Monaco-20"))
    )
  )
 ((string-equal system-type "gnu/linux") ; linux
  (progn
   (add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(font . "DejaVu Sans Mono-20")) )
  )
 )
(set-face-font 'menu "-*-*-*-*-*-*-20-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")
(set-face-font 'default "-*-*-*-*-*-*-20-*-*-*-*-*-*-*")

(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(height . 60))
(add-to-list 'default-frame-alist '(width . 120))
```

I think I should set the size of the emacs window relatively to the size of the screen but I don't know how to do it in twm, or maybe I should put a switch depending on the vnc session.

does anybody know how to do that?